# flash action script 2: how can i create custom events?

Tags: flash, events, actionscript-2

I would like to create my own events. 
In action script 3 I can just extend the event class and create my own Event Class.
how can I achieve the same results using action script 2?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mx.events.EventDispatcher:

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/204/1/Using-EventDispatcher/Page1.html

Here's a SO question with a good answer on how to do AS3 style events in AS2:

[Best practice for ActionScript 2 events - is there a way to simulate ActionScript 3-style events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709107/best-practice-for-actionscript-2-events-is-there-a-way-to-simulate-actionscript)